# how to write ls command in c using execvp

Tags: c, linux, shell, ls, execvp

i am trying to write a simple ls command so i'm input "ls r" and i want to check if my code is allright. the output does not showing anything. this is the code:

```
int main(void){

  char *line;
  char *args[16];
  pid_t pid; 

    line = (char*)malloc(1024);
    printf("$ "); 
    fgets(line,1024,stdin);
     args[0] = strtok(line, " ");
     args[1] = strtok(NULL, " "); 

    printf("%s\n" , args[0]);
    printf("%s", args[1]);

    execvp(args[0], args);
}
```

thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look inside the source code of existing free software shells (i.e. `sash` or [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Read [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) man page. Notice that `execvp` can fail. When it succeeds, *it does not return*! Also, [stdout(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html) is *buffered*, you need to call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html).

You are probably missing some basic understanding (a shell is [forking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) processes, read also [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) & [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) etc...)

Try first:

```
int main(void){
 char line[1024];
 char *args[16];
 memset (args, 0, sizeof(args));
 printf("$ ");
 fflush(NULL); 
 fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
 args[0] = strtok(line, " ");
 args[1] = strtok(NULL, " "); 
 printf("%s\n" , args[0]);
 printf("%s", args[1]);
 fflush(NULL);
 execvp(args[0], args);
 perror("execvp");
 return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Don't forget the relevant `#include` directives needed by [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html), `fgets`, `execvp`, `perror`.

Read also [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...

Compile using `gcc -Wall -g`. Learn how to use the debugger `gdb` and also `strace`

BTW, real shells don't use [strtok(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html); they parse the line explicitly (and they have to, since a shell can escape a space with a backslash or a quote).

Actually, try `strace ls`; you'll find out that `/bin/ls` uses [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).

Comment: Link to Advanced Linux Programming is broken.

Comment: Thanks. the output show me now "exevcp: bad address" what does it means?

Comment: Read *carefully* `execvp(3)` & `execve(2)` man pages. There is a constraint on `args` that you are not following. I improved my code. But you need to read a lot.